# Conditionally Disable/Enable submit button based on different field types in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with numeric fields, text fields and drop down lists. I have implemented functionality were if a field is changed from original value then button is enabled for submit. If field is changed back to it original value button should(is) disabled.

**PROBLEM**: Current issue at the moment is
- if I change two different fields, then button is enabled as expected. But then if I revert only one of these edited fields back to its original value, submit button is disabled. Expected behavior is "as long as there's a changed field that is valid, then button should remain enabled for submit".

**Conditions for button state**
for all fields - if original value is changed and is not empty - enable button
for numeric fields - if entered/changed value is a valid number - enable button

[image: Form sample]

*so if any of these conditions are not met, then button should stay disabled

**Current Code**
Current implementation and why it was implemented this way

```
$("input[name='q_description'],[name='q_sellprice'],[name='profit'],[name='grossProfit'],[name='markUp']").change(function () {
        var originalValue = ($(this)[0].defaultValue);
        var currentValue = $(this).val();
        var changed = false;
        var button = $('#submit-data');

        //numeric fields
        var sellprice = parseFloat($('#q_sellprice').val());             
        var profit = parseFloat($('#profit').val()); var grossProfit = parseFloat($('#grossProfit').val());
        var markUp = parseFloat($('#markUp').val()); 

        //text fields
        var description = document.getElementById("q_description").value;

        //alert("Numeric values:" + getFieldValues );

        //$('input, select').bind('keyup change blur', function () {
            if (description == "" || isNaN(sellprice) || isNaN(profit) || isNaN(grossProfit) || isNaN(markUp))                 
            {
                /*change background color to red for invalid or empty field*/
                $(this).css("background", "#fd6363");
                document.getElementById("submit-data").disabled = true;
            }
            else if ((originalValue != currentValue)  ) {
                /*change background color to yellow if value changed*/
                $(this).css("background", "#FFE075");
                document.getElementById("submit-data").disabled = false;
            }
            else if (originalValue == currentValue) {
                /*original and current values match, reset background of that field to white*/
                $(this).css("background", "#FFFFFF")
                document.getElementById("submit-data").disabled = true;
            }
            else {
                //to do
            }  
        //});             
    });
```

On the first line, I dont have it this way

```
$("input[type=text]").change(function () {
```

because there is some fields on the form/page that I wanted to ignore for affecting the state of the submit button. That is why I have specified those particular fields on the .change

Also to check isNaN for the numeric fields. I probably can identify id the required fields by class names and add them to an array and just check that instead of the numerous declarations

```
var numericFields = document.getElementsByClassName("numeric_fields");
var getFieldValues = new Array();

 for (i in numericFields) {
 var singleValue = numericFields[i].value;
 if (singleValue !== "" && singleValue !== undefined ) {
             getFieldValues.push(singleValue);
         }
 }
```

but I had an issue, where the invalid check if statement part of the code wasn't getting hit with that implementation.

*Anyways the main issue that I would like to solve at the moment, is to stop the button getting disabled when I revert one field back to its original value when multiple fields have been changed/edited to (from original) other valid states.*

**UPDATE**
Further checks to clarify issue. I added an alert message message to see/check which if/else statement is getting hit each time any field is changed

```
if (description == "" || isNaN(sellprice) || isNaN(profit) ||    isNaN(grossProfit) || isNaN(markUp))                 
{
/*change background color to red for invalid or empty field*/
   alert("1") //disable button
}
else if ((originalValue != currentValue)  ) {
/*change background color to yellow if value changed*/
   alert("2") //enable button
}
else (originalValue == currentValue) {
/*original and current values match, reset background of that field to white*/
   alert("3") //default -> disable button
}
```

Now if a previously edited field is reverted back to its original value, while another has been changed, its hitting the last else statement alert("3), meaning the check is done per individual field that is currently being edited and not all the specified fields that I have specified from the form.